# In R, how do I subset a data frame that spans over time and across space on the basis of a temporal event

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, subset

More specifically: I have a data frame (`my.df`) that resembles the one below,

```
  City       Month Answer
  Montreal   Jan      n
  Montreal   Feb      n
  Montreal   Mar      n
  Toronto    Jan      oui
  Toronto    Feb      n
  Toronto    Mar      n
  Calgary    Jan      n
  Calgary    Feb      n
  Calgary    Mar      yes
```

Now, I need to subset in terms of the feature labeled `Answer`. More precisely, If `Answer` is `oui` (like for Toronto in January) or `yes`, (like for Calgary in March) I need to get something like

```
  City      Month Answer
  Toronto   Jan      oui 
  Toronto   Feb      n
  Toronto   Mar      n
  Calgary   Jan      n
  Calgary   Feb      n
  Calgary   Mar      yes
```

In other words, a data frame containing no entries for Montreal (which has neither oui nor yes).

My data frame is `dim(37045, 41)` and there are some messy entries under `Answer`, like `ouu`, `yess`, or `oii`. I have tried to use regex in combination with `%in%` like in:

```
  oui <- grep('ou', Answer)    
  yes <- grep('ye', Answer)    
  oui.yes <- union(oui, yes)
  ans <- my.df[oui.yes, 3]    
  new.df <- my.df[Ans %in% my.df$Answer, ]
```

Unfortunately, the resulting `new.df` is exactly the same as `my.df`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Ignacio Vera.

Comment: you need to learn basic manipulations on data frames, e.g. `my.df$AnswerNew = ifelse(my.df$Answer %in% c('ou','ye','oui','y','yes','yess','ouu'), 'yes', 'n')`, functions `transform` and `subset` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use `ave` from `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(Answer %in% c("oui", "yes"), City, FUN=any)),]
#      City Month Answer
#4 Toronto   Jan    oui
#5 Toronto   Feb      n
#6 Toronto   Mar      n
#7 Calgary   Jan      n
#8 Calgary   Feb      n
#9 Calgary   Mar    yes
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[,.I[any(Answer %in% c("oui", "yes"))], by=City]$V1,]
#      City Month Answer
#1: Toronto   Jan    oui
#2: Toronto   Feb      n
#3: Toronto   Mar      n
#4: Calgary   Jan      n
#5: Calgary   Feb      n
#6: Calgary   Mar    yes
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(City = c("Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Toronto", 
 "Toronto", "Toronto", "Calgary", "Calgary", "Calgary"), Month = c("Jan", 
 "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), Answer = c("n", 
 "n", "n", "oui", "n", "n", "n", "n", "yes")), .Names = c("City", 
"Month", "Answer"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close.

```
dat <- structure(list(City = c("Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Toronto", 
       "Toronto", "Toronto", "Calgary", "Calgary", "Calgary"), Month = c("Jan", 
       "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar"), Answer = c("n", 
       "n", "n", "oui", "n", "n", "n", "n", "yes")), .Names = c("City", 
       "Month", "Answer"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L

dat[dat$City %in% unique(dat[dat$Answer %in% c("yes", "oui"),]$City),]

##      City Month Answer
## 4 Toronto   Jan    oui
## 5 Toronto   Feb      n
## 6 Toronto   Mar      n
## 7 Calgary   Jan      n
## 8 Calgary   Feb      n
## 9 Calgary   Mar    yes
```

You can split that out (for readability):

```
positive_cities <- unique(dat[dat$Answer %in% c("yes", "oui"),]$City)
dat[dat$City %in% positive_cities,]
```

And, there are a myriad of other ways to accomplish this.